# Laravel - php artisan migrate doesn't work

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3, laravel-artisan, laravel-migrations, artisan-migrate

I'm trying to migrate my auth tables but when i do `php artisan migrate` nothing happens. It shows no error, nothing.

[image]

Before run this command i ran `php artisan make:auth` and work well.

Thanks

Comment: It takes a long time if you have a lot of migrations, how long have you waited?

Comment: more than 5 minutes @AntoinB

Comment: Okay, definitely not normal then. Maybe you have errors but disabled their display on the console on PHP side?

Comment: i don't have any error from php side...

Comment: What about log file?

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have migration that were not ran yet. If you have one, run `composer dumpauto` command to register this migration and then run `php artisan migrate` again.

You can find all executed migrations in the `migrations` table.

Comment: It is the first time that i'm running this command. I just have the user and password table @AlexeiMezenin

Comment: @AntoineB thanks for edit, but `composer dumpauto` exists. It's an alias for `dump-autoload`

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin Indeed, sorry, I couldn't find anything about it on Google and had never heard of it so I thought it was an error but I tested and it's working :P